# How can I add field content to an asset in code?

Tags: upload

I'm trying to upload an asset based on this code https://gist.github.com/sathoro/8178981
which works fine, but how can I add additional content fields during the upload? I would like to set the caption an additional fields like credit during the upload?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It propbably works to store the custom field directly with your new element model:

```
$assetFileModel->setContentFromPost(array(
    'captionFieldHandle' => $myCaption,
));
```